# Which regular expression will get all group matches between start regex and end regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pattern-matching, regex-group

I try to get all group matches between the first occurrence of a start regex and the last occurrence of an end regex in python.

Here is a (very simplified) specific example in which I try to get all the strings which consist of alphanumerical characters + white space + numbers, and are between parentheses. The result should be ["B 2", "C 3", "D 4"], but I don't get it working.

```
import re

s = "A 1 (B 2 C 3 D 4) E 5"

re.findall("(\w+\s\d+)", s)                   # ['A 1', 'B 2', 'C 3', 'D 4', 'E 5']
re.findall("(?<=\()(\w+\s\d+)", s)            # ['B 2']
re.findall("(\w+\s\d+)(?=\))", s)             # ['D 4']
re.findall("(?<=\()(\w+\s\d+)(?=\))", s)      # []

# desired result: ["B 2", "C 3", "D 4"]
```

My attempts do not limit the search area, but modify the pattern of the group match itself, which I don't want to achieve.

I would appreciate help.

Best regards

AFoeee

Comment: is `slice` can help you `re.findall("(\w+\s\d+)", s)[1:-1]`?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because in the actual use case I do not know the number of elements before or after the area which is limited by the start regex and end regex. The example in my question is very simplified. But thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Demo:**

```
import re

s = "A 1 (B 2 C 3 D 4) E 5"
m = re.search(r"\((?P<content>.*?)\)", s)
if m:
    val = m.group("content")
    print(re.findall(r"\w\s+\d", val))
```

**Output:**

```
['B 2', 'C 3', 'D 4']
```

*If you have multiple values in parenthesis then*

```
s = "A 1 (B 2 C 3 D 4) E 5 (X 2 Y 3 Z 4) V 4"
for m in  re.findall(r"\(.*?\)", s):
    print(re.findall(r"\w\s+\d", m))
```

**Output:**

```
['B 2', 'C 3', 'D 4']
['X 2', 'Y 3', 'Z 4']
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it in one Regexp?

Comment: Sorry. I am not sure how to do that in a single regex